# Spacy - Max length currently 10 for phrase matching; max length is 9

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to create a rule-based phrase matcher with Spacy 2.0. I have a list of strings to match, which I run through an NLP pipe and remove the ones longer than 9 tokens (max for Spacy PhraseMatcher). This has worked for me previously, however, when I do it now, I get an error as if I have 10+ tokens in some documents. Below is a minimally reproducible version of my code, with different matches (in actuality I'm matching over a huge set, but the list comprehension filter should still apply.)

```
matches = [u'This! Is! An! Example! of! a! Long! String!', u'This ain\'t']
docs = [d for d in list(nlp.pipe(matches)) if len(d)<10]
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('things', None, *docs)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         2 docs = [d for d in list(nlp.pipe(matches)) if len(d)<10]
>         3 matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
>   ----> 4 matcher.add('things', None, *docs)
>
> matcher.pyx in spacy.matcher.PhraseMatcher.add()
>
> matcher.pyx in spacy.matcher.get_bilou()
>
> ValueError: [T001] Max length currently 10 for phrase matching